# Hide elements that won't fit on screen using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm looking for a way to dynamically hide/show a elements based on if they would fit into the current screen width.

Normally objects are either pushed down onto a new row, or cause horizontal scrolling, if elements will not fit onto the screen. That's not what I'm trying to do.

I was also hoping to do this without media queries, and would rather use jQuery.

I think what I need to do is for each element check if the right edge of the element would be outside of the right edge of the screen, and if so hide that element. However this is a bit above my jQuery experience.

I have the elements all aligned horizontally already, and when the screen gets smaller they push down the page and show in multiple rows. I assume with jQuery I can get a more fluid effect, whereas with CSS media queries I'd need to set up a bunch of queries to show/hide each element based on screen size.

Can someone point me in the right direction? There may already be a similar question here on SO, but I'm not quite sure what to search for, as I haven't had much luck so far finding out how to do this searching SO, or using Google.

I have found solutions like [How to hide elements on screen size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44833570/how-to-hide-elements-on-screen-size) but they all seem to require setting some predefined screen sizes. I was hoping to have jQuery do this automatically without specifying widths ahead of time.

Comment: you ask the same question with the same kind of content.

Comment: I don't know what question to ask. This is more specific, and less broad, than my last question.

Comment: This question is just about detecting the edges of the element/screes and hiding elements. The rest of the stuff from my last question I have already figured out. This, from this question, is the one part I'm stuck on. I can't show code if I have no idea what this code looks like. If I did, I wouldn't need to ask here.

Comment: Just think about it. If you were lost and asked for directions, how frustrating and unhelpful would it be if the person asked you to draw them a map of all of the wrong places you walked first. That wouldn't help you at all. It's the same here. I'm lost. I don't even know where to start to do what I'm trying to do. All I'm asking is to be pointed in the right direction, and you're acting like I want someone to write it all for me. That's not what I want at all.

Comment: Looking at my browser history, I've been searching for info on this for 2.5 hours already. So I wasn't being lazy and expecting others to do the work for me. I'm stuck, and just need to be pointed in the right direction.

Comment: If you want to "hide" elements off the edge of the screen use the CSS property of `overflow-x: hidden` for the containing element. However, depending on the widths of other items though you may find your first element clipped. But it could possibly work for your scenario.

Comment: @Reddog that gives me an idea to use along with what Jaxon said in his answer. I have an idea to try now that I'm hoping will work.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

It will check every element that you select that it's width is less than the viewport width, if so it hides it.

```
$(function() {

var checkScreenSize = function (){

    var viewportWidth = $( window ).width();

    $('.select-elements-you-want-to-check').each(function () {
        if($(this).width() > viewportWidth){
            $(this).hide();
        }
        else {
            $(this).show();
        }
    });


}

// run on doc ready
checkScreenSize();

// run on window resize
$( window ).resize(checkScreenSize);

});
```

Comment: Thank you. That does look close enough to what I'm trying to do. I'm going to try this out now, and will mark your answer as correct if it works. And thanks for your help. Sometimes after a long day, and not knowing exactly what you're looking for, it's hard to find help here. So thank you :)

Comment: No probs   how'd you go?